# GNU plot and animation (on windows)

Tags: gnuplot

I want to know how can i save an animation or each plot on Gnuplot. For example, in this data file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GexyqFWcEEmVTYnim-AAx8wya_uVhLC/view?usp=sharing
when i plot the result from the Fromm scheme "gnuplot  plot_fromm.gnu" then press enter i can see the animation but i would like to save it as a gif file or an animated png, or several png files in order to recreate the animation.

```
set yrange[-0.25:1.25];
plot 'transport000.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport000.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause -1;
plot 'transport001.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport001.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport002.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport002.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport003.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport003.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport004.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport004.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport005.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport005.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport006.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport006.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport007.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport007.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport008.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport008.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport009.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport009.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
plot 'transport010.dat' u 1:2 w l, 'transport010.dat' u 1:11 w lp;
pause 0.25;
```

Do i need to put

```
set terminal png
set output
```

before each plot or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two gnuplot terminal types (e.g. output modes) support animation.

**(1)** gif animation has been supported for many years

```
  # delay is time between frames in units of 0.01 second (default = 5)
  # loop <n> adds a request to loop only <n> times (may be ignored by the player)
  set term gif animate {delay <d>} {loop <n>} 
  set output 'myanimation.gif'
  FILE(i) = sprintf("transport%03d.dat", i)
  do for [i=0:10] {
     plot FILE(i) u 1:2 w l, '' u 1:11 w lp
  }
  unset output
```

**(2)** The current development version also support webp animation

```
 Syntax:
         set term webp
                      {size <x_pixels>,<y_pixels>}
                      {font <font>} {fontscale <scale>} {{no}enhanced}
                      {{no}transparent} {background <rgbcolor>
                      {linewidth <lw>} {rounded|butt|square} {dashlength <dl>}
                      {pointscale <ps>}

                      {{no}animate {quality <q>} {delay <msec>} {loop <n>}}

 Individual frames produced by the webp terminal are first created as 32-bit
 RGB + alpha channel images using routines shared with the pngcairo terminal.
 See `set term pngcairo` for more details about font and terminal options.
 The frames are then converted to webp format on output.

 The `animate` option produces a webp file containing multiple frames,
 each one created by a separate `plot` or `splot` command.  The animation
 sequence is terminated by the next `set output` or `set terminal` command.

 `quality` (1..100) affects the size of the output file.
 q values from 1 to 74 use lossy compression; smaller values produce a
 smaller file at the cost of lost detail in the rendered image.
 q values from 75 to 100 use lossless compression. All produce the same
 image quality (lossless!). Larger values spend more computing time for
 diminishing benefit in reduced file size.
 The default is 75, lossless compression without excessive computation.

 The `delay` suboption sets the delay time in milliseconds between frames
 during playback (default 50 milliseconds).

 The `loop` suboption specifies how many times the animation sequence should
 be repeated during playback.  The default (0) gives a continuous loop.
```